# Count repeated records in a table with different column name

Tags: sql, sql-server

Hi I am newbie in sql and this is my problem: I have this table:

> rhp1----rhp2----rhp3----rhp4---rhp5 .....
>
> 51-------32------61------54-----32 ....
>
> 21-------95------125-----25-----45 ...
>
> 65-------58-------58-----69-----25 ...

I want to count how many every field value repeated in this table! for example: 51 in first field , how many 51 do we have in this table and ....

with this query I can get this in one column:

```
select rhp , count(1) as count_rhp from tbl_all 
group by rhp
order by count_rhp Desc
```

How can I do this for the whole table?

Comment: Your question isn't very clear.  Can you show us your desired output?

Comment: Is there any difference between rhp1/rhp2/rhp3/etc? I think the reason the question is hard to answer is because they really shouldn't be different columns in the first place.

Comment: no they are the same! the reson i put 1,2,3,4 for them is that i cant put the same rhp name for diferent columns in sql. it is a data set with 7 clasess of rhp and i want to count how many a field value repeted in the whole data set.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Union all columns into one, then group by and count:

```
with tbl_all (rhp) as
(
 select rhp1 from tbl union all
 select rhp2 from tbl union all
 select rhp3 from tbl union all
 select rhp4 from tbl union all
 select rhp5 from tbl 
)
select rhp , count(1) as count_rhp 
from tbl_all 
group by rhp
order by count_rhp Desc
```

Comment: thankssssss its working just fine ^_^ i got my answer thank you

Comment: @meysammotamedi, be sure to check the mark under the votes to mark as answer.